# Javascript amateur's problem

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
  jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){    
      $('.Testimonials').each(function(){
        var theContent = $(this).html();
        theContent = '-' + theContent;
        });
    }); // END doc ready
  }); // END function
```

Basically I wanted to add a text before an option (unable to do it by css). What am I doing wrong?

I tried like this as well:

```
$('.Testimonials').insertBefore($(this).html(), $('text'))
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please read [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722), especially [#behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) section. Re-write your code using Drupal way instead of `.ready`, and then ask again, if you will still see this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way, i don't see any reason to to use `each()` function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Testimonials').text('sample text '+$(this).text());

      }); // END doc ready
```

It will add text before each element having class **Testimonials**.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Testimonials').each(
                    function()  
                        {
                            $(this).text('- '+$(this).text());
                        }
    );
  }); // END doc ready
```

It worked!!